# amount of returned values - REST API angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using regular REST API with Angular like under the link: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-by-example-httpclient-get/

In the function:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
    })  
  }
```

can we get into `data` and get to know how many elements is returned?

I need to know how many elements are returned from backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API returns array `data: any[]`. Javascript Array has `length` property which shows the total number of items in the array. All you need is to use `data.length`. If you are dealing with data, then you probably need to know the basics of Array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 0):

If data is an array simply use length property.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any[])=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
      this.productsLength = data.length;
    })  
  }
```